# How show json data with database in symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have a little problem, because I have to show json date with database in Symfony3.

My controller

```
/**
     * @Route("/api/rest", name="rest_api")
     * 
     * 
     * @Template
     */
public function indexAction(Request $Request) {

    $Repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CommonUserBundle:Comment');
    $row = $Repo->findAll();


    $data = json_encode($row, true);

    return array(
        'comment' => $data
    );
}
```

And this is my layout in html.twig

```
{% for comments in comment %}
           {{ comments }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I don't know why nothing show.
Help me please :)

Comment: Why do you want to encode it as json?

Comment: So are you trying to return json, or render a twig template?

Comment: This is my request to job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok using my deductive skills (as your question is a bit vague) I am going to make the opposite assumption as everyone else did and say use the [JSON helper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#json-helper) function (Since 3.2).

```
return $this->json($myThings);
```

If you are working in older versions you need to return a proper [Response object](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) with the headers and such.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  {% for comments in comment %}
       {{ comment }}
  {% endfor %}
```

If it doesn't work try to change and you want to print an array

```
$data = json_encode($row, true);
```

to 
 `$data = json_decode(json_encode($row), true);`

if you want to print the string try this inside your twig

```
{{ dump(comments) }}
```

instead of this

```
{% for comments in comment %}
       {{ comment }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: No he has @template annotation

Comment: ops sorry update answer with a new solution, thanks @goto

Comment: Yea, probalby I have to use object Response but I don't know how

Comment: When I use decode json I have error ,,Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given''

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` return a string.

Twig

```
{{ dump(comments) }}
```